# Loop in r to run script

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to run a script for each station (I was replacing the numbers 1 by 1 in the script) but there're more than 100 stations.

I thought maybe loop in script could save my time. Never done loop before, don't know if it's possible to do what I want. I've tried as the bellow but doesn't work.

Just a bit of my df8 data (txt):

```
RowNum,date,code,gauging_station,precp
1,01/01/2008 01:00,1586,315,0.4
2,01/01/2008 01:00,10990,16589,0.2
3,01/01/2008 01:00,17221,30523,0.6
4,01/01/2008 01:00,34592,17344,0
5,01/01/2008 01:00,38131,373,0
6,01/01/2008 01:00,44287,370,0
7,01/01/2008 01:00,53903,17314,0.4
8,01/01/2008 01:00,56005,16596,0
9,01/01/2008 01:00,56349,342,0
10,01/01/2008 01:00,57294,346,0
11,01/01/2008 01:00,64423,533,0
12,01/01/2008 01:00,75266,513,0
13,01/01/2008 01:00,96514,19187,0
```

Code:

```
station <- sample(50:150,53,replace=F)

        for(i in station) 
          {

        df08_1 <- filter(df08, V7==station [i])

        colnames(df08_1) <- c("Date","gauging_station", "code", "precp")


        df08_1 <- unique(df08_1)


        final <- df08_1 %>%
          group_by(Date=floor_date(Date, "1 hour"), gauging_station, code) %>%
          summarize(precp=sum(precp))


        write.csv(final,file="../station [i].csv", row.names = FALSE)

    }
```

Comment: 1) what doesnt work as expected? 2) can you set `i` to a single value and run everything inside the loop as expected?

Comment: You need `paste` to turn `"station[i]"` into a string and concatenate with `"../"` and `".csv"`

Comment: Doesn't run the filter imediatly. The idea was to run the script for each station. I had 1 final df to each station. What I was doing was 1 by 1 and export to csv. The code runs if I change station [i] for the number of the station.

Comment: It's probably faster if you do the `summarize` for all stations then write each station to individual files

Comment: It's easy to `split` by `station_id` then use `sapply` + `write.csv`

Comment: I'll try those options, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not averse to using some `tidyverse` packages, I think you could simplify this a bit:

Updated with your new sample data - this runs ok on my computer:

#### Code:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  select(-RowNum) %>%
  distinct() %>% 
  group_by(date_hour = lubridate::floor_date(date, 'hour'), gauging_station, code) %>%
  summarize(precp = sum(precp)) %>%
  split(.$gauging_station) %>%
  purrr::map(~write.csv(.x,
                        file = paste0('../',.x$gauging_station, '.csv'),
                        row.names = FALSE))
```

#### Data:

```
dat <- data.table::fread("RowNum,date,code,gauging_station,precp
                  1,01/01/2008 01:00,1586,315,0.4
                  2,01/01/2008 01:00,10990,16589,0.2
                  3,01/01/2008 01:00,17221,30523,0.6
                  4,01/01/2008 01:00,34592,17344,0
                  5,01/01/2008 01:00,38131,373,0
                  6,01/01/2008 01:00,44287,370,0
                  7,01/01/2008 01:00,53903,17314,0.4
                  8,01/01/2008 01:00,56005,16596,0
                  9,01/01/2008 01:00,56349,342,0
                  10,01/01/2008 01:00,57294,346,0
                  11,01/01/2008 01:00,64423,533,0
                  12,01/01/2008 01:00,75266,513,0
                  13,01/01/2008 01:00,96514,19187,0") %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
```

Comment: I've no problems with tidyverse. My code is a lot worst than that. I've the input data separated by years because the dplyr package doesn't work in my new computer, and I've to run in the old one (but has problems to compute large files). I'll adapt your code to my data. I'll let you know. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment for a lack of reputation, but if the code works if you change station [i] for the number of the station, it sounds like each station is a part of and has to be extracted from the df08 object (dataframe).

If I understand you correctly, I would do this  as follows:

```
stations <- c(1:100) #put your station IDs into a vector

for(i in stations) { #run the script for each entry in the list

  #assuming that 'V7' is the name of the (unnamed) seventh column of df08, it could
  #work like this:
  df08_1 <- filter(df08, df08$V7==i)    #if your station names are something like 
  #'station 1' as a string, use paste("station", 1, sep = "")

  colnames(df08_1) <- c("Date","gauging_station", "code", "precp")

  df08_1 <- unique(df08_1)


  final <- df08_1 %>%
    group_by(Date=floor_date(Date, "1 hour"), gauging_station, code) %>% 
    summarize(precp=sum(precp))     #floor_date here is probably your own function


  write.csv(final,file=paste("../station", i, ".csv", sep=""), row.names = FALSE) 
  #automatically generate names. You can modify the string to whatever you want ofc.

}
```

If this and all of the other examples don't work, could you provide us with some dummy data to work with, just to see what the df08 dataframe looks like? And also what the `floor_date()` function does?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I'll try to share my data